# Windows Phone 8 HttpClient didn't response all Post data

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, http-post

I want to POST string data windwos phone 8 like this:

```
using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler())
        {
            if (handler.SupportsAutomaticDecompression)
            {
                handler.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip |
                    DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
            }
            using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
            {
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
                    new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                var fromUrlEncodedContet = 
                    new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>()
                    {
                        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("aliasno1","01120"),
                        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("aliasno2", "89479"),
                        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("aliasno3", "1"),
                        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("myregion", "006"),
                        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("myregiontitle", "IZMIR")
                    };

                using (var response = await client.PostAsync("http://m.kentkart.com/kws.php", 
                    new  FormUrlEncodedContent(fromUrlEncodedContet)))
                {
                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        var data =  response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

when i click button and breakpoint data. i saw response data like this;

> {"time_webacc":"1.6927719116211E-5!!","refreshCount":0,"time_HOST":"4.0054321289062E-5!","servicetimediff":5102,"timedifference":"5102 (host) "}

I didn't recived all data. Respons data must be

balanceresult: "8,75"
chargeAmt: "10"
chargeresult: "20140125152910"
func: "bs"
refreshCount: 0
servicetimediff: 354
time_HOST: "0.3545618057251!"
time_bal_stat: "0.0059030055999756!"
time_balance: "0.34575796127319!"
time_webacc: "0.0028519630432129!!"
timedifference: "341 (ws) / 354 (host) "
usageAmt: "2"
usageresult: "20140126123248"

I made something wrong, but i don't understand where is my mistake..

Comment: Why do you think your response should be as you posted, it is not a valid json,xml etc?

Comment: Hi, I'm using developer tool (F12) in browser, go http://m.kentkart.com then select "BAKIYE SORGULAMA" (left-bottom) then select Izmir, and enter 01120 - 89479 -1 .I clicked network tab and  i saw response like this. I need use balanceresult , chargeAmt

Comment: Have you change any code? Can you share your code please if its possible.Maybe i can't read response json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you post wrong parameters

```
using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler())
{
    if (handler.SupportsAutomaticDecompression)
    {
        handler.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
    }

    using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
    {
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Referrer = new Uri("http://m.kentkart.com/");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
            new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        var fromUrlEncodedContet =
            new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>()
        {
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("func","bs"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("val", "0112089479"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("myregiontitle", "Izmir"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("myregion", "006"),
        };

        using (var response = await client.PostAsync("http://m.kentkart.com/kws.php",
            new FormUrlEncodedContent(fromUrlEncodedContet)))
        {
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var data = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                dynamic obj = await JsonConvert.DeserializeObjectAsync(data);
                var balance = Convert.ToDecimal((string)obj.balanceresult, CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("tr-TR"));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

BTW: the server returns `balanceresult` as `"8,75"`. A more correct result would be `8.75`(without `"`s)